# SQL Server stored procedure: not saved under folder "Stored Procedure", parameters not recognized

Tags: sql, sql-server

SQL Server doesn't find parameters in database and stored procedures are not saved under the folder "Stored Procedure". I first did execute and then refresh on stored procedure but nothing happened. So, then, I did save but it create a file out of the database.

It doesn't recognize `@`, `char`, `varchar` etc...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE (Inserisci_Nuovo_Amminoacido) 
    @Nome VARCHAR(30)
    @Simbolo_A_Tre_Lettere CHAR(3)
    @Simbolo_A_Una_Lettera CHAR(1)
    @Peso_Molecolare FLOAT
    @Tipologia_Gruppo_R VARCHAR(30)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT a.Id_Amminoacido
               FROM Amminoacidi AS a
               WHERE a.Nome = @Nome)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 10 -- Amminoacido già presente nel sistema 
    END

    DECLARE @Id_Amminoacido INT = NULL

    SELECT 
        @Id_Amminoacido = MAX(a.Id_Amminoacido) 
    FROM
        Amminoacidi AS a 

    IF @Id_Amminoacido IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Id_Amminoacido = 0
    END

    SET @Id_Amminoacido = @Id_Amminoacido + 1

    INSERT INTO Amminoacidi (Id_Amminoacido, Nome, 
                             Simbolo_A_Tre_Lettere, Simbolo_A_Una_Lettere,
                             Peso_Molecolare, Tipologia_Gruppo_R)
    VALUES (@Id_Amminoacido, @Nome, 
            @Simbolo_A_Tre_Lettere, @Simbolo_A_Una_Lettera,
            @Peso_Molecolare, @Tipologia_Gruppo_R)

    RETURN 1 -- Va bene 
END
```

Comment: Schema ? Might be created under the schema of logged in user

Comment: Thank you for having answered. I am a beginner and I don't know how I can find this schema of logged in user and how I can modified it. Could you tell me how I can modify it, please?

Comment: I checked in Schemas under Security but there are not store procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Inserisci_Nuovo_Amminoacido  
(
    @Nome VARCHAR(30) ,
    @Simbolo_A_Tre_Lettere CHAR(3),
    @Simbolo_A_Una_Lettera CHAR(1),
    @Peso_Molecolare FLOAT,
    @Tipologia_Gruppo_R VARCHAR(30)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT a.Id_Amminoacido
               FROM Amminoacidi AS a
               WHERE a.Nome = @Nome)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 10 -- Amminoacido già presente nel sistema 
    END

    DECLARE @Id_Amminoacido INT = NULL

    SELECT 
        @Id_Amminoacido = MAX(a.Id_Amminoacido) 
    FROM
        Amminoacidi AS a 

    IF @Id_Amminoacido IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Id_Amminoacido = 0
    END

    SET @Id_Amminoacido = @Id_Amminoacido + 1

    INSERT INTO Amminoacidi (Id_Amminoacido, Nome, 
                             Simbolo_A_Tre_Lettere, Simbolo_A_Una_Lettere,
                             Peso_Molecolare, Tipologia_Gruppo_R)
    VALUES (@Id_Amminoacido, @Nome, 
            @Simbolo_A_Tre_Lettere, @Simbolo_A_Una_Lettera,
            @Peso_Molecolare, @Tipologia_Gruppo_R)

    RETURN 1 -- Va bene 
END
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for having answered. Yes, it works. Thank you so much.